# Service, get & extend in javascript and how are they being used

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to make sense of some code snippets in javascript. But getting way too confused, it seems to be using all the symbols in all possible ways.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  metrics: inject.service(),

  activate() {
    this._trackPage();
  },

  _trackPage() {
    run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => {
      const page = document.location.href;
      const title = this.routeName;

      get(this, 'metrics').trackPage({ page, title });
    });
  }
});
```

q1: What are the keyword service, get, extend? What are they doing here?
q2: Why is activate defining _trackPage separately? Why not put the reschedule code in activate() itself?

---

Basically trying to understand: https://emberway.io/applying-the-adapter-pattern-for-analytics-in-ember-js-apps-29448cbcedf3

---

Comment: Activate is simply calling _trackpackage, activate and _trackpackage are defined on the object you are exporting

Answer (score 0):

A [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/applications/services/) is a place to put code that can be used almost anywhere in the app. In order to make the code inside a service available to the script you're working on, you inject it.

`get` is a helper that is used to access things like the service or Ember objects. In more recent tutorials, you'll see syntax that looks more like `this.get('metrics')`. See the [docs here](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Object/methods/get?anchor=get).

You could put the `_trackPackage` code into the `activate` function if you wanted to. However, activate is a special function called a hook, and many developers like to keep their route hooks like activate as short and sweet as possible for stylistic reasons. Hooks are special functions that fire automatically on things like a user entering a route, rerenders, etc. There are many kinds of hooks like this throughout Ember.

Extend is Ember boilerplate that gets created for you when you use the Ember CLI to make new files. Basically, when you create a route, you're extending on Ember's default route configurations, attributes, and methods. So there's some base behavior (like the activate hook) that gets inherited.

I recommend that you read the Ember Guides sections on objects and services for more info.

Comment: So would below be an overall equivalent code ?
`import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  activate() {
    run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => {
      const page = document.location.href;
      const title = this.routeName;
      inject.service().trackPage({page, title});
    }
  }`

Comment: I don't think that service injection would work. You should inject it and then use get it this.get, in a similar way as the original example you showed.